# Errors in the script after upgrading tables

Tags: google-apps-script

After the table updates , the error occurred during execution : rang.sort. Here is the complete tex procedure.

```
function myFunction () {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet ()
    var range = ss.getSheets () [ 0 ] .getRange ("O2: O");
        range.sort ({column: 15 , ascending: false})
} ;
```

Error: Sorry, a server error occurred . Please try again later . And so every time ..

Comment: You're getting 1 column range, how can you be sorting column 15? Just guessing...

Answer (score 0):

```
    var range = ss.getActiveSheet().getRange("O2: O");
    range.sort ({column: 15 , ascending: false})
```

Or use the getSheetByID or getSheetByName or getSheets().next(), I don't think getSheets()[0] works.

Comment: Neither is obtained . Help me please. I need a function that updates the task in the filter table , with mutations both values ​​in a particular column .